# Cant install certbot using snap return: Run configure hook of "certbot" snap if present

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, certbot, snap

I want to install certbot using snap, but when I tried [Official instruction](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/snap-apache.html):

```
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

but returns:

> error: cannot perform the following tasks:
>
> - Run configure hook of "certbot" snap if present (run hook "configure": /var/lib not root-owned 1000:1000)

Previously, I uninstalled certbot(from apt) by using the below command:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y certbot python3-certbot-apache
```

What happened? I am using ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

From the error, looks like I need to change owner of `/var/lib` to root user.  But I changed and still got the same error. Should I change to root recursively to that folder?

here is `ls` to the  `/var/lib`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 AccountsService
drwxr-xr-x  5 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 24  2020 apache2
drwxr-xr-x  5 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  4 02:36 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root      root      4.0K Sep  8 02:03 binfmts
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K May  5  2018 command-not-found
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 dbus
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Apr 16  2018 dhcp
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 dictionaries-common
drwxr-xr-x  7 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  4 02:36 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Dec  9  2019 git
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 grub
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  3 14:52 initramfs-tools
drwxr-xr-x  2 landscape landscape 4.0K Mar 10  2020 landscape
drwxr-xr-x  4 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  4 02:34 letsencrypt
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 locales
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  3 06:25 logrotate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root      root         0 Oct  4 02:56 lxcfs
drwxr-xr-x  2 lxd       nogroup   4.0K Jun 16 00:42 lxd
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 man-db
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Apr 24  2018 misc
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  3 06:25 mlocate
drwx------ 35 mysql     mysql     4.0K Oct  3 14:51 mysql
drwx------  2 mysql     mysql     4.0K Mar 24  2020 mysql-files
drwx------  2 mysql     mysql     4.0K Mar 24  2020 mysql-keyring
drwxr-xr-x  2 root      root      4.0K Jan 21  2020 mysql-upgrade
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  3 14:50 pam
drwxr-xr-x  4 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 24  2020 php
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Apr  4  2019 plymouth
drwx------  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 polkit-1
drwxr-xr-x  6 postgres  postgres  4.0K Oct  3 14:50 postgresql
drwx------  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 private
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 24  2020 python
drwxr-x---  2 redis     redis     4.0K Feb 24  2021 redis
drwxr-xr-x 21 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  4 02:46 snapd
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 sudo
drwxr-xr-x  7 root      root      4.0K Oct  4 02:36 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root      4.0K Jun 27 13:26 ubuntu-advantage
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  3 14:53 ubuntu-release-upgrader
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  3 14:52 ucf
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Nov 25  2019 unattended-upgrades
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 update-manager
drwxr-xr-x  4 myuser       myuser       4.0K Oct  4 02:44 update-notifier
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 ureadahead
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 usbutils
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser       myuser       4.0K Mar 10  2020 vim
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to change `/var/lib/snapd` folder to root user using bellow command:

```
chown root:root -R /var/lib/snapd/
```

In other server, `/var/lib` folder and the inside is owned by root. I don't exactly know why the user of the folder on this server is not root, after changed it now I can install certbot and use it.